# Javascript: typeof shows 'object', then null pointer thrown

Tags: javascript

Maybe someone can shed light on this.

I'm getting JS's version of an NPE on occasion, even though logging shows that typeof the offending variable is 'object'.

Here's the logging:

```
typeof myVar: object
ERROR in main._getFolderCount(): TypeError: myVar is null
console.error("ERROR in main._getFolderCount(): " + e);
```

Here's the code:

```
try{
  console.log('typeof myVar: ' + typeof myVar);
  if (typeof myVar !== 'undefined' && typeof myVar !== 'null'){
    if (currentMsgsObj && currentMsgsObj.folderId == data[i].id && myVar.totalRows!=data[i].count) {        
      myVar.totalRows=data[i].count;
    }
  } else { 
  }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("ERROR in main._getFolderCount(): " + e);
  }
}
```

So you can see that the logging shows myVar is typeof 'object', and the code appears to pass the 'undefined/null' check, and then proceeds to blow up when a myVar member is accessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `null` type is [spec'd](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3) to return `object` when using the `typeof` operator upon it.

Comment: woah, learned something.  I thought null behaved like undefined, and that === 'null' would work like === 'undefined'.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, `typeof null == 'object'`.

You can check whether something is `null` using `===`:

```
if (blarg === null) ...
```

Using `typeof blarg == 'null'` will never work.